# Are Operating System tags useful/appropriate for SQA?

Tags: discussion

There are several tags, that have been created on SQA that are for Operating Systems. Is it really appropriate to have tags specific to Operating Systems?

iOS - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios

Android - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android

Windows - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows

Unix - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix

Could the posts with these tags have better tag options that are more related to testing than OS?

Comment: I would expect the platform you use to be relevant to testing. Admittedly not every case, but often times you don't know it's relevant until you actually track down the problem. Do you have any alternatives, or could you elaborate on what specifically you feel is inappropriate about OS tags?

Answer (score 2):

I think that these tags are appropriate for a Software Quality Assurance & Testing.

Each operating system behaves differently regardless of what you are looking at. even browsers behave differently because they are constructed differently for each operating system, because each operating system is constructed differently, if they were not then they would not be different operating systems.

These are good tags. Some might even be missing.